# Upload multiple images in Vue.js and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload multiple files at once in vue.js and laravel, Code that i'm using is :

> Vue.js code:

```
 <input type="file" v-validate="'required'" multiple @change="uploadDegree" name="uploadDegree" placeholder="Upload Degree"/>

  uploadDegree(e)
            {
                for (let file of e.target.files) {
                    try {
                        let reader = new FileReader();
                         reader.onloadend = file => {
                         this.user.degree_attachment= reader.result;
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);                      
                    } catch {}
                }
              }
```

> Laravel Code:

```
 $files = $request->input('degree_attachment');
           foreach($files as $file) {
               $degreename = time() . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1])[1];
                $pathDegreeExist = public_path("img/degree_img/"); 
                if(!File::exists($pathDegreeExist)) File::makeDirectory($pathDegreeExist, 777);
                $img = \Image::make($file);
                $img->save(public_path('img/degree_img/').$degreename); 
                $newUser->degree_attachment = $degreename;
            }
```

> I'm getting this error :

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

where i'm trying to get image,

Comment: `$files = $request->file('degree_attachment');` not `input()` it is `file`

Comment: @KamleshPaul: tried but still getting same error

Comment: your sending as base64 ? it should be `this.user.degree_attachment.push(reader.result)` then it will be array and you can loop over

Comment: @KamleshPaul: I have tried your code but it is still giving me `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 0):

there are two problems , the one mentioned in the comment

and another i noticed in your vue code , you are overriding the variable `this.user.degree_attachment` with the file content each time , so first its not multiple uploads second its type wont be an array so laravel controller wont know how to deal with hence the `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` simply because its not iterative object type .

well i didnt try it on the laravel part , i tested the vue in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-worker-mfpbl?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) and console logged the array with the content of each file as an array item , but this normally is triggered by your laravel validation .

```
   uploadDegree(e) {
      let a = [];
      for (let file of e.target.files) {
        try {
          let reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = (file) => {
            a.push(reader.result);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          this.degree_attachment = a;
        } catch {}
      }
      console.log(this.degree_attachment);
    },
```

Comment: Tried still getting `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: return or dump the $files , whats its type ? is it not iterable ??